# I'm trying to learn the basic of ajax. I want to send a form data using post method to the server and get back a response text that's all

Tags: php, ajax

I know how to use the GET method but is hard to understand the POST method with a form.

I'm sure there is something wrong with the line request.send(); but I'm sorry I couldn't get it.

Also what If there is more than one field like I want to send name + email

My HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>AJAX Demo 2</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="demo2.php" method="post">
            Email: <input type="email" name="email" required >
        </form>
        
        <button onclick="loadContent()">Load</button>
        
        <div id="ServerContent">
           <p></p>
        </div>
        
        <script>
            function loadContent(email){
                //Create request object 
                let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                let email = document.getElementsByName("eamil").values;
               //Create event handler that specifies what should happen when server responds
                
                request.onload = function(){
                    
                    //Check HTTP status code
                    if(request.status == 200){

                        //Get data from server
                        let responseData = request.responseText;
                        
                        //Add data to page
                        document.getElementById("ServerContent").innerHTML = responseData;
                    }
                    else
                        alert("Error communicating with server");
                }

               //Set up request with HTTP method and URL 
               request.open("POST", "demo2.php", true);
               xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
               //Send request
               request.send();
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My PHP code

```
    <?php
    

//Get email string - need to filter input to reduce chances of SQL injection etc.
    $emailString = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);

    if($emailString != ""){//email string exists
        echo 'Hello ' . $emailString;//Output message with contents of query string
    }
    else{//Query string parameter 'email' cannot be found
        echo 'Hello stranger';
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = "url to your php file";

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("POST", url);

xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "application/json");
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
   if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
      console.log(xhr.responseText);
   }};

var data = `{
  "email": "youremailvariable",
  "name": "yournamevariable"
}`;

xhr.send(data);
```

Try this way

Comment: Thanks for your response and time. I have tried it.  I think something wrong with my PHP or HTML